# How to use longitude and latitude from a map to load map apps on mobile devices from a web app

Tags: iphone, web-applications, maps, latitude-longitude

I have a mobile web app which has a google map feature and a button to click to get directions to the specific location, at the moment it takes you to the mailing address location within the mobile map app. Is there a way to code it so that it marks the area with long and lat instead of the mailing address? The marker on the map on the website is marking the long and lat, which is already saved on my website. So I already have all the info needed, just not sure what to change to get the mobile maps to load the location properly. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.